# Datepicker getDate method works on second click and show previous selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker inline and have problem with get date value.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="datepicker-container"></div>

$('.datepicker-container').datepicker({
    maxViewMode: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    language: "pl",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$(".datepicker").on('click', 'td', function(event){
    console.log( $('.datepicker-container').datepicker("getDate") );
});
```

When I select date, it works only on second time and show previous selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your date picker click event as below ..

```
$(".datepicker").on('click', function(event){
    //You code goes here
});
```